# How do you understand this line from H264 specifications

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, h.264

In the H264 (mpeg4 part 10 AVC) specifications available [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-H.264-201201-S), we can read the following on page 59 (a little bit simplified for the clarity of the question on SO):

```
for(i8x8 = 0; i8x8 < 4; i8x8++) 
  for(i4x4 = 0; i4x4 < 4; i4x4++) 
     if(CodedBlockPatternLuma & (1 << i8x8))
       doSomething()
```

I am wondering how to interpret the content of the `if` statement. Looking at other implementations it seems that the test to be done is to check whether it's 0 or not. It seems to make more sense, otherwise the condition can only be evaluated to `true` when `i8x8` is `0`.  How do you understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is testing whether or not a particular bit is set. The 1 << i8x8 is taking a "1" bit and shifting it left a variable number of spaces, then &'ing it to the CodedBlockPatternLuma to see if a bit is set. If the pattern is 10101010 and the i8x8 is 2, then the pattern gets ANDed with 100, so 10101010 & 00000100 = 00000000, the bit is not set.
If pattern was 01010101, and ANDed with 00000100 then the bit would be set, and it would be true.

Comment: Arggg, I'm so tired and working with a DSL language where Integers can't be tested as boolean. As a consequence I wrote (X & (1 << i8x8)) == 1 !!!

Comment: @Manuel Selva `== 1` is wrong here. Instead add `!= 0`, that is always correct.